# Is there an open source alternative to Flash for web animation?

Tags: flash, open-source, animation, frameworks

I want to make something similar to [this](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2009/02/02/sports/20090202_superbowl_twitter.html), but I'd like to avoid proprietary platforms (flash). I'm relatively new to development and I'm willing to learn anything. I understand that some javascript frameworks like jQuery and MooTools are capable of some animation, but is this beyond their capability? What do you recommend?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at John Resig's [processing.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/).  No need to use raw jQuery when jQuery's primary author already done the work!

Comment: Thanks! A friend of mine showed me this a long time ago before I could appreciate what it was. This will do the trick, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use FlashDevelop for the IDE

http://osflash.org/flashdevelop

Also, you can use gnash as the player.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/

Comment: I think he's asking about the actual platform, not the player.

Answer (score 1):

The more important question is, if you found such a platform would anyone be able to play it with software they already have installed?

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head:  Flash is ubiquitous... it makes some sense to take advantage of that.

Comment: that's why I'm thinking about JS frameworks

Answer (score 1):

What about Java or JavaFX?  I actually don't know a whole lot about it but it's supposed to be for RIAs which puts it into the Flash and Silverlight class of technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [SVG is capable of animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html), but I don't know how widespread the support is or what tools support it.

Comment: as usual on w3 specs: everyone except IE

Comment: It works in IE with a plugin. Though good luck when trying to get visitors to install it.

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the animation you pointed to would be very difficult in JQuery, but not impossible. Question is, are you up for the challenge?

I wouldn't recommend alternatives to Flash unless the app you are building is internal to your company and you can be sure everyone will have the necessary plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Processing](http://processing.org).

Also check out the free [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/) SDK, which allows you to write and compile Actionscript without the Flash IDE

Answer (score 0):

You could use Moonlight, the open source clone of Silverlight.

Comment: I believe Moonlight is only a player.  You would still need to use Microsoft tools to create the content.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java space:

- [JavaFX](http://www.javafx.org) already had [100.000.000 downloads](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonathan/entry/javafx_hits_100_000_000) if you're worried about adoption.
- [Processing](http://processing.org). You'd still have to worry about the download size. IMHO, processing is great for prototypes, but you have to do quite a lot of work to make the applet performant, especially when no animation is going.